# Replace Missing[Unmatched] with zero

Tags: associations

After a left `JoinAcross`, I have a number of `Missing["Unmatched"]` values in my list of associations.  I'd like to set them all equal to zero. I tried the following:

```
q = JoinAcross[Normal[reported], Normal[estimates], Key["key"], "Left"];
q1 = q /. Missing["Unmatched"] -> 0;
q[[100]]
q1[[100]]
```

> ```
> <|"key" -> "2009-ABCDE", "ActuarialEPI" -> 26603.6, 
>   "ReportedEP" -> 28535., "ReportedLI" -> 0., "ELI" -> 25619.3, 
>   "DLI" -> 25619.3, "EstimatesEP" -> Missing["Unmatched"]|>
>
> <|"key" -> "2009-ABCDE", "ActuarialEPI" -> 26603.6, 
>   "ReportedEP" -> 28535., "ReportedLI" -> 0., "ELI" -> 25619.3, 
>   "DLI" -> 25619.3, "EstimatesEP" -> Missing["Unmatched"]|>
> ```

#### Edit

I neglected to mention that I need to do this to the entire list of associations. I used element 100 as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can supply default values like this:

```
defaults = <|"EstimatesEP" -> 0|>;
data = <|"key" -> "2009-ABCDE", "ActuarialEPI" -> 26603.6, 
   "ReportedEP" -> 28535., "ReportedLI" -> 0., "ELI" -> 25619.3, 
   "DLI" -> 25619.3, "EstimatesEP" -> Missing["Unmatched"]|>;

<|defaults, DeleteMissing@data|>
```

> ```
> <|"EstimatesEP" -> 0, "key" -> "2009-ABCDE", 
>  "ActuarialEPI" -> 26603.6, "ReportedEP" -> 28535., 
>  "ReportedLI" -> 0., "ELI" -> 25619.3, "DLI" -> 25619.3|>
> ```

In order to set any key to zero by default you can use

```
default = AssociationThread[Keys[data] -> ConstantArray[0, Length@Keys[data]]];
```

> ```
> <|"key" -> 0, "ActuarialEPI" -> 0, "ReportedEP" -> 0, 
>  "ReportedLI" -> 0, "ELI" -> 0, "DLI" -> 0, "EstimatesEP" -> 0|>
> ```

This solution can easily be applied to a list of `Association`s:

```
data2 = ConstantArray[data, 3];
<|defaults, DeleteMissing@#|> & /@ data2
```

Comment: Thanks your solution works, but I don't understand it.  In the simpler case with just 1 element in the association, how does <|defaults, DeleteMissing@data|> do the substitution?

Comment: @MitchellKaplan Please read [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17115880#17115880) including especially WReach's answer to that question, which establishes the rules that `Asssociation` adheres to. `Association` flattens its arguments and when the same key appears several times the last key always wins. In my solution `default` precedes `data` so it is usually overwritten, but when I delete keys with missing values `defaults` will not be overwritten for those keys.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of alternatives:

```
assoc = <|"key" -> "2009-ABCDE", "ActuarialEPI" -> 26603.6, 
   "ReportedEP" -> 28535., "ReportedLI" -> 0., "ELI" -> 25619.3, 
   "DLI" -> 25619.3, "EstimatesEP" -> Missing["Unmatched"]|>;

Map[# /. Missing["Unmatched"] -> 0 &, assoc]
(*
  <|"key" -> "2009-ABCDE", "ActuarialEPI" -> 26603.6, 
   "ReportedEP" -> 28535., "ReportedLI" -> 0., "ELI" -> 25619.3, 
   "DLI" -> 25619.3, "EstimatesEP" -> 0|>
*)

Block[{Missing},
 Missing["Unmatched"] = 0;
 Map[Identity, assoc]
 ]
(*
  <|"key" -> "2009-ABCDE", "ActuarialEPI" -> 26603.6, 
   "ReportedEP" -> 28535., "ReportedLI" -> 0., "ELI" -> 25619.3, 
   "DLI" -> 25619.3, "EstimatesEP" -> 0|>
*)
```